# Range loop fails after it's first iteration

Tags: vba

Have this code to loop through a range looking for row duplicates in two of four columns. When a match is found, I resize the row to copy and paste all four columns to another sheet and delete those two rows from sheet 1. Beginning on iteration 2, the code starts both loops on the new "first row" and matches itself. The issue seems to be that once I delete the row assigned the "c" variable, the range must be reinitialized as the next loop does not assign c a value. I have tried all the suggestions below but none have resolved the issue, anyone have any ideas?

Initail Data:

LM176   |    Bank-BB&T     |        (0.20)  |   2/12/2018

NA1119  |    BB&T          |         0.21   |   2/14/2018

NA1119  |    Bank-BB&T     |        (0.21)  |   2/14/2018

LM641   |    Wells Fargo   |           0.30 |   2/14/2018

LM6251  |    Wells Fargo   |           1.00 |   2/10/2018

LM6251  | Bank-Wells Fargo |       (1.00)   |   2/14/2018

AT11    |  Wells Fargo     |           2.00 |   2/13/2018

AT11    |  Bank-Wells Fargo |         (2.00)|   2/14/2018

Desired Data:

LM176   |    Bank-BB&T      |       (0.20)   |  2/12/2018

LM641   |    Wells Fargo    |          0.30 |    2/14/2018

With matched rows being copied to another sheet(works fine)

```
Dim c As Range, d As Range 

Worksheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set c = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

     For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

             For Each d In Worksheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)").Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)



                  If c = d And c.Offset(0, 2).Value = d.Offset(0, 2).Value * (-1) Then

                       c.Resize(1, 4).Copy
                       Worksheets("Clears-Feb").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                       d.Resize(1, 4).Copy
                       Worksheets("Clears-Feb").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                       d.EntireRow.Delete
                       c.EntireRow.Delete                       

            End If               

    Next
    Next
```

Comment: What do you mean "the correct rows"? The first row is still the first row?

Comment: Starting with iteration 2, the value in line "B2" which has now changed since I deleted two rows above it, is ignored. The code selects line "B3" and uses that for variable "c" and "d" and matches itself.

Comment: Actually, starting with iteration 2, c does not get assigned a value, instead It's value is indicated as "Object Required". D gets assigned the value in cell B3 and the code matches the D value to itself. Thanks for the help

Comment: show an example of "initial" data and "final" desired data after processing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must realize that working with ranges forces you to deal with the case the range is not there anymore!

so, once you start the `For Each c In...` loop you are setting `c` to an actual range and when you execute `c.EntireRow.delete` then the `c` range variable is *vanished* and may be the `Next` variable, too!

I propose you to use loops with row index as loop iterator so that you can easily both adjust it after any row deleting and adjust its ending condition, too

so you may try this (untested, but commented) code:

```
Dim c As Range, d As Range

Dim iRow1 As Long, iRow2 As Long
Dim copied As Boolean

With Worksheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)") ' reference wanted worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Set c = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    iRow1 = 2
    Do
        Set c = .Cells(iRow1, 2)
        iRow2 = iRow1 + 1 'start searching duplicates from the row below current iRow1
        Do
            Set d = .Cells(iRow2, 2)
            If c.Value2 = d.Value2 And c.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = d.Offset(0, 2).Value2 * (-1) Then 'use Value2 to deal with plain cell content
                If Not copied Then 'if firts duplicate found
                    c.Resize(1, 4).Copy targetSht.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)  'copy/paste the current iRow1 duplicate
                    copied = True 'mark down current iRow row is to be eventually deleted
                End If

                 d.Resize(1, 4).Copy Worksheets("Clears-Feb").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'copy/paste the current iRow2 duplicate
                 d.EntireRow.Delete
                 iRow2 = iRow2 - 1 ' draw iRow2 back one row since you just deleted the current iRow2 and with subsequent updating it'll point to the real next row
            End If
            iRow2 = iRow2 + 1 'update current iRow2
        Loop While iRow2 <= .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row 'loop until you reach the actual last not empty cell in column B
        If copied Then 'if any duplicates actually found...
            c.EntireRow.Delete 'then delete current iRow1 row. the next row to start with will remain the same
            copied = False ' clear the "tobe deleted" mark for iRow1 row
        Else 'otherwise
            iRow1 = iRow1 + 1 'update iRow1 row to start searching duplicates from
        End If
    Loop While iRow1 < .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row 'loop until you reach the cell before the actual last not empty one in column B
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
For c = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
         For d = c + 1 To Worksheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)").Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)



              If Cells(c, 2) = Cells(d, 2) And Cells(c, 2).Offset(0, 2).Value = Cells(d, 2).Offset(0, 2).Value * (-1) Then

                   Cells(c, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy
                   Worksheets("Clears-Feb").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                   Cells(d, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy
                   Worksheets("Clears-Feb").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                   Cells(d, 2).EntireRow.Delete
                   Cells(c, 2).EntireRow.Delete



            End If

    Next d
```

Next c

Comment: Thanks. that returns "Run Time Error 13, Type Mismatch" on line 2.  I had tried the "+1" but I don't think that's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can change 2 row. 
    For d = c + 1 To ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
and I did not write:      next c

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: This update causes the C variable to be an integer, instead of the value in the cell. i.e. C = 1, D = value in cell, C =2, D = value in cell, so a match is never found.

Comment: In the "If" box, the changes are made.     Example Cells(c, 2) = Cells(d, 2), that is, C and D are numbers, but the values of the cells are compared.

Comment: ok, so running this code, only integer values appear on any line and the code never matches anything when it should, nearly every two lines in the data are matches.

Comment: I apologize, I was floating over the variable instead of the cell reference. C and D are indicating they match, but the code still jumps to the next iteration without copying, pasting, or deleting. I think it's not matching the second test (using the offset cells).

Comment: Stepping through the code, both C and D do match (I removed the second column test to verify), but the code simply keeps jumping as if no match was found. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub a()

For c = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For d = c + 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

          If Cells(c, 2) = Cells(d, 2) And Cells(c, 2).Offset(0, 2).Value = Cells(d, 2).Offset(0, 2).Value Then

               Cells(c, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy
               Worksheets("Clears-Feb").Activate
               lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
               Cells(lr, 2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

               Cells(d, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy
               Cells(lr, 2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2018 Daily Cash (Feb)").Activate

               Cells(d, 2).EntireRow.Delete
               Cells(c, 2).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

Next d
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This one has some other errors, but you can see how it works. To make a good product, you need to work with data. So, that's all I can do.